# Generate votes for a URL

Tags: twitter

I have an idea that I wnat some feedback on/sugestions. I have a list of 3000 rules and sugestions that are on a public website and at the moment they are in either an aspx or Sharepoint page. I want to move this data to a blogging platform, but I want to list them not in time order, but in a ranked order.

I would like to use this algorythm:

```
Rank = ([Facebook Likes] + [Tweets] + [Digs] + [Pingbacks] + [Trackbacks]) * [Google Rank]
```

- Facebook Likes - I should be able to call the API
- Tweets - ***I was going to use backtype, but it costs money. Any ideas?***
- Digs - I can get this through the DIG API
- Pingbacks - Not realy sure how to do this one
- Google Rank - I should be able to call a Google API

The only things I am worried about are the Tweets and Pingbacks, and maybe they get dropped, but I was hoping that someone would have an idea how to go about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about Pingbacks but I know people typically publish *shortened* versions of URLs on Twitter.  Some of the URL shortening sites, such as [bit.ly](http://bit.ly), will give you statistics for those URLs.  There is an API available for [bit.ly](http://code.google.com/p/bitly-api/wiki/ApiDocumentation) but I'm not sure about the other services.

I'm not sure this helps you out now but might be something to keep in mind for the future.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, that does help, but bit.ly seams to only keep stats for a short time.